# Why my Wpf Popup is placed on the wrong side?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I make a Wpf code, which create the Popup from C# code. And I hope to place the Popup on the right side of a UserControl, but this only happens when I set `popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Left;` Quite strange!

### Note:

- `MainWindow` has a `Grid` called `MyGrid`.
- A `UserControl` called `MyUserControl` will be embedded in `MyGrid`.

[image]

This is the UserControl xaml code:

```xml
<Grid Background="AliceBlue" Width="270" Height="100">
    <Button Width="50" 
            Height="20" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Click="TestButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

C# code as below.

1. My idea is to transfer a parameter (MyGrid in MainWindow) to the UserControl (MyUserControl) when creating it in MainWindow.

   ```
   public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        UIElement Parent = null;
        public delegate void TestButtonMouseClick(UIElement target);
        public static event TestButtonMouseClick ETestButtonMouseClick;

        public MyUserControl(UIElement parent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Parent = parent;
        }

        private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ETestButtonMouseClick?.Invoke(Parent);
        }
    }
   ```

For the MainWindow, its xaml code is as below.

2. This MyGrid could be anywhere in the MainWindow, and I use it as the container of the UserControl.
3. When click the button, the delegate will transfer the paramter (MyGrid) as target of the Popup's PlacementTarget.

Finally, when I set `popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Left`; then as the picture shown above: the Popup appears on the right side of the UserControl. And if I set `popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Right`, then the Popup will appear on the left side of the UserControl. Why?

The workable demo project can be found here:
https://github.com/tomxue/MyPopupIssue.git

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Width="270"
          Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

And its C# code behind is:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyUserControl userControl = new MyUserControl(MyGrid);
    MyGrid.Children.Add(userControl);
    MyUserControl.ETestButtonMouseClick += MyUserControl_ETestButtonMouseClick;
}

private void MyUserControl_ETestButtonMouseClick(UIElement target)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() =>
    {
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
        popup.PlacementTarget = target;
        popup.HorizontalOffset = 10;
        popup.VerticalOffset = 41;
        popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Left;
        popup.StaysOpen = false;

        TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        myTextBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        myTextBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        myTextBlock.Width = 166;
        myTextBlock.Height = 170;
        myTextBlock.Text = "Just a test.";
        myTextBlock.FontSize = 22;
        myTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        myTextBlock.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        popup.Child = myTextBlock;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }));
}
```

**More:**
I tested yeaterday night at home. And just now I tested again at office. Below picture shows my issue again. And I use Visual Studio 2022 Community version.
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Running your app from github the popup is on the left side and changing to `PlacementMode.Right` let the popup appear on the right side - as expected

Comment: @SirRufo Thank you for your reply! I test it again just now, and still repeat the issue. Please check my main post, the last part. So it might be even more weird.

Comment: And again, I can not reproduce it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBRIw.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with touch screen support. You have definitely touch screen support and "Sir Rufo" doesn't. So on touch devices Left and Right are swapped (right/left handedness support can maybe also impact the behavior).

Workaround:

```
var isTouchDev = Tablet.TabletDevices.OfType<TabletDevice>().Any(dev => dev.Type == TabletDeviceType.Touch);

var popup = new Popup();
popup.AllowsTransparency = true;

popup.Placement = isTouchDev ? PlacementMode.Right : PlacementMode.Left;

popup.PlacementTarget = target;
popup.VerticalOffset = 41;

popup.HorizontalOffset = isTouchDev ? -10 : 10;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, mine is a touch screen. Great knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

For those who define the Popup in XAML, an alternative option is to employ a Markup extension. This extension dynamically adjusts the placement of the `Popup` based on the handedness of the device, determined by the `MenuDropAlignment` setting:

```cs
public class HandednessToRightAlignmentValueExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    static readonly PlacementMode PlacementOnRightSide;

    static HandednessToRightAlignmentValueExtension()
    {
        PlacementOnRightSide = SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment ? PlacementMode.Left : PlacementMode.Right;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return PlacementOnRightSide;
    }
}
```

It is then can be used in the `Popup` definition to provide the correct placement value:

```xml
...
 <Popup Placement="{Converters:HandednessToRightAlignmentValue}"
        PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=adorner}">
...
```

Please be aware that the `HandednessToRightAlignmentValueExtension` presumes that the handedness setting remains unchanged throughout the application's execution. However, should this not be the case, you can move the `PlacementOnRightSide` evaluation from the static constructor to the `ProvideValue` method.

In order to check the value of `MenuDropAlignment`, run `Win + R` and execute `shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}`.